# QML Repeater removes all delegate items and regenerates them again when model changes

Tags: c++, qt, qml, repeater

By changing the model (adding or subtracting or editing a member of the model), the repeater removes all the created items (delegates) and rebuilds them again. For heavy models, this is a big problem.

How can I change the repeater, so that instead of removing all delegates, it only deletes the item related to the deleted member, and when a member is added, it creates only the item related to it, and in case of editing a member of the model, only that member is removed and recreated.

I studied the code related to the [Repeater](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickrepeater.cpp.html#_ZN14QQuickRepeaterC1EP10QQuickItem), but due to the use of private methods and classes in its source, I cannot reimplement it.

You can test the problem with the bellow code:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
        
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Ronia Components")

    property var repeatreModel: [1, 2]

    Timer {
        interval: 2000
    running: true
    repeat: true

    property int count: 0
    onTriggered: {
             count++;

             // Add an item into ,odel
             repeatreModel.push(count);
    }

}

Column {
        anchors.fill: parent

    Repeater {
        id: repeater
        model: repeatreModel
        clip: true

        onItemRemoved: (item, index) => {
                         console.log("Remove : (item, index) ", item, index)
                       }

        onItemAdded: (item, index) => {
                      console.log("Add : (item, index) = ", item, index)
                     }

        delegate: Rectangle {

            width: 50
            height: 40

            Text {
                id: name
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: modelData
            }
        }

        onModelChanged: console.log("modelChanged")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Integer and JavaScript array models are read-only* [[1](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#changing-model-data)]. Therefore, you cannot update the model, and any changes will recreate all of your instances. You should use [ListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html) instead.

Comment: @GrecKo, I post an answer according to SMR's guide, I want an answer not to change the model because my model is used a lot in the software and needs drastic changes.

Comment: *Short answer*? You can't.

*Long answer*? You can, but you need to rewrite all QML since there is no way to find out which element changed in a JS array using C++.

*Best answer*? Rewrite and clean your code. This is the best practice and the right path to take.

*Alternative answer*? Override `Repeater` in the QML side, write a function to diff between the last and current array state, and assign it to a `ListModel`. This would decrease performance but result in fewer changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SMR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11603485/smr) said:

> Integer and JavaScript array models are read-only [1](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#changing-model-data). Therefore, you cannot update the model, and any changes will recreate all of your instances. You should use [ListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html) instead.

Based on that, I figured out one of the possible solutions:

```
 import QtQuick
 import QtQuick.Controls
    
    Window {
        width: 640
        height: 480
        visible: true
        title: qsTr("Ronia Components")
    
        Timer {
            interval: 2000
            running: true
            repeat: true
    
            property int count: 0
            onTriggered: {
                count++;
                listModel.append({"counter": count, "counter2": count*10})
            }
    
        }
    
        ListModel {
            id: listModel
        }
    
        Repeater {
            id: repeater
    
            model: listModel
            clip: true
    
            onItemRemoved: (item, index) => {
                               console.log("onItemRemoved: = ", item, index)
                           }
    
            onItemAdded: (item, index) => {
                             console.log("item, index = ", item, index)
                         }
    
            delegate: Rectangle {
    
                x: counter + 2
                y: counter2 + 20
                width: 20
                height: 20
    
                Text {
                    id: name
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: counter2  + counter
                }
            }
    
            onModelChanged: console.log("modelChanged")
    
        }
    }
```

**Note:**

I do not to want change the model, because my model is used a lot in the software, and needs drastic changes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Repeater for large models.
Prefer ListView or similar items (TreeView, TableView).
Quote from [Qt's documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-repeater.html):

> Considerations when using Repeater
>
> The Repeater type creates all of its delegate items when the repeater
> is first created. This can be inefficient if there are a large number
> of delegate items and not all of the items are required to be visible
> at the same time. If this is the case, consider using other view types
> like ListView (which only creates delegate items when they are
> scrolled into view) or use the Dynamic Object Creation methods to
> create items as they are required.

Comment: Hi, ListView or similar changes the layout and position of each delegate. Thanks